# Why DataType.Password validates only on server-side?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have model as

```
[Required]
[EmailAddress]
[Remote("EmailValidation", "Account", ErrorMessage = "{0} already has an account, please enter a different email address.")]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

and form for registration as:

```
<form id="registrationForm">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, String.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger text-center" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ForModal, new { @Value = true })
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <div class="input-group margin-top-10 margin-bottom-5">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="input-group margin-top-10 margin-bottom-5">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="input-group margin-top-10 margin-bottom-5">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Confirm Password" })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-u btn-u-orange btn-u-wide" title="Join">Join</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When i type short password - validation fires, when i type confirPassword different as Password - validation fires, but when i type only digits as `123456` nothing happens on client-side, just on server-side, after all i get error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYi3d.png (link for screenshot)

Why i can get validation DataType.Password on client-side?

---

As i search about such problem in internet, i just get solution like `use Html.PasswordFor or Html.EditorFor instead of Html.TextBoxFor`.

Comment: is the required validation working client side?

Comment: @Batavia, yes. you can see it on sceenshot http://i.imgur.com/jY8bymy.png

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `DataType` attribute is not used for validation out the box, it's used primarily for rendering. For example, if you use `EditorFor` to render a property internally it will use the `DataType` attribute to determine what type of input it should render i.e. `<input type="password" ... />`. `PasswordFor` basically does the same thing but without the need for the `DataType` attribute.

Your length validation works client-side because that's handled by the `StringLength` attribute not `DataType`. If you want to enforce specific data-type validation I suggest you look at using the [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), outwith that you would be looking at implementing your own [custom validator](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/).

Comment: then what validates password on server-side?

Comment: From what I can see you have 2 validation rules on your password - it cannot be null and must be at least 6 characters long, there is no other validation on it (unless you are doing something at the backend we can't see). However, the error message itself would suggest that your password isn't even reaching the server as the validation error indicates it's missing.

Comment: the compare validator is the one that should be doing the comparing, there is no reason that couldn't be done clientside in this case

Comment: @Batavia my answer is not talking about the compare, the OP is talking about when they type only digits no client-side validation is firing....the reason for this is because there is no validation rule in place for that. As far as the validator is concerned `123456` is both a value & at least 6 chars long therefore is deemed acceptable.

Comment: @James, well, sorry, you are wright! "Validation" is goes from UserManager<T> from AspNet.Identity.Core.